# Jquery add class to input

Tags: javascript, jquery

i got this jquery script, it puts placeholder "+" in my search input, and probblem is that, now every input got "+" placeholder on my website,

how to add only particulary class to this js code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('input').on('focus',function(){
    $(this).attr('placeholder',"");
});
$('input').on('blur',function(){
    $(this).attr('placeholder',"+");
});

});
```

Comment: Just call `addClass` with your class in `$(this)`? [jQuery addClass](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/)

Comment: Put the class name in the selector... `$("input.className")`

Comment: As `Archer` said you can select something like this `$("input.myClass[type=text]")`

Answer (score 1):

This is quite simple jQuery code. A google search would have found you an answer. You just need to specify the class name:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('input.CLASSNAME').on('focus',function(){
    $(this).attr('placeholder',"");
  });
  $('input.CLASSNAME').on('blur',function(){
    $(this).attr('placeholder',"+");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an identifier like `class` or `id` where you want to update the `placeholder`

Hope this snippet will be usefull

**JS**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('input').on('focus',function(){
    $(this).attr('placeholder',"");
});
// add placeholder to input which have class updatePlaceholder
$('input.updatePlaceholder').on('blur',function(){
    $(this).attr('placeholder',"+");
});

});
```

**HTML**

```
<input type = "text">
<input type = "text" class = "updatePlaceholder">
```

Check this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/nubswt2t/)